# Serial doesn't name a type: mbed cli on windows

Tags: c++, mbed

Actually i'm trying to do a data logging from an ax3 accelerometer, using mbed cli on windows 10 and stm32l476rg, i colned the project from github, did all steps but can't compile my program, i even tried a hello word Serial but doesn't work, please i'm new in mbed cli on windows, any help would by appriciated.
[image]

Comment: do you `#include "mbed.h"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, all of these errors were simply due to compatibility issues, the project I imported from git was not compatible with the latest version of mbed os, so working with an older version of mbed os was the solution.
thank you all!